# Internet Explorer submit form not working

Tags: html, internet-explorer

The code below is working on Google Chrome and Firefox but not on Internet Explorer 11. I have an image and I created a mapping for it. I have tried different ways for submitting a form and calling the javascript function. I noticed that the mapping only works when i have a button, but then the form submit doesn't work. When using button type="submit" it still doesn't submit but the javascript function is called.

I want a mapping of an image and that the form will be submitted and the javascript function will be called.

```
<div>
    <img src="keys.jpg;" height="480" width="640" border="1" usemap="#keysmapping">
    <map name="keysmapping">

    <form method=GET>
    <input type="submit" name="key" value="2" onclick="setTimeout('updateImage();',100);"><area class="one" shape="rect" coords="0,0,90,85"></input>
    </form>

    <form method=GET>
    <button type="submit" name="key" value="3" onclick="setTimeout('updateImage();',100);"><area class="two" shape="rect" coords="95,0,195,85"></button>
    </form>

    <form method=GET>
    <input type="text" name="key" value="4">
    <button onclick="setTimeout('updateImage();',100);"><area class="three" shape="rect" coords="195,0,290,85"></button>
    </form>
    </map>
</div>
```

Comment: whats the `updateImage()` function?

Comment: This is my javascript function.

<script type="text/javascript">  
 function updateImage() {
 img = document.getElementById('screenImage');
 img.src = 'screen.jpg?' + Math.random();"
 } 
</script>

Comment: are you sure you've enabled scripts in `Internet Explorer` settings?

Comment: yes the scripts are enabled in IE. The scripts are working in IE. But submitting a form, calling the javascript function and having a mapping doesn't work

Comment: Actually I don't understand how this should work at all. By submitting the form, the page will be reloaded and your `setTimeout` callback `updateImage` should not be fired. You might want to explain what are you actually trying to do.

Comment: I have an embedded device where this webpage is running. This webpage is a remote for this device. I have an image of the buttons of the device. I created a mapping for the buttons.


when I press a button, I want to submit the form so the value 2 will be sended to the device. The device will go to the menu. With the updateImage, the new screen of the device will be sended to the webpage.

And this is working in Chrome and Firefox. But I have read that IE doesn't automatically submit forms when pressing enter.

Answer (score 0):

After trying for 2 days I found a solution to the problem.

I think it had to do with the design of the HTML and now am I manually submitting the form.

```
    <form method="get" name="myFormOne">
        <input type="text" name="key" value="2">
        <area alt="One" shape="rect" coords="0,0,95,110" onclick="document.myFormOne.submit();setTimeout('updateImage()',100);">
    </form>

    <form method="get" name="myFormTwo">
        <input type="text" name="key" value="3">
        <area alt="Two" shape="rect" coords="96,0,210,110" onclick="document.myFormTwo.submit();setTimeout('updateImage()',100);">
    </form>

    <form method="get" name="myFormThree">
        <input type="text" name="key" value="4">
        <area alt="Three" shape="rect" coords="211,0,310,110" onclick="document.myFormThree.submit();setTimeout('updateImage()',100);">
    </form>
</map>
```